# CrateDB & Elasticsearch problem running as root and binding IP

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cratedb

so i am trying to install CrateDB on a brand new centos7 box and i am running into issues. When running ./crate -Cnetwork.host=[myip] i recieve the following errors

```
[2018-11-23T11:05:20,857][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Tête de Gaulent] initializing ...
[2018-11-23T11:05:20,873][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [Tête de Gaulent] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupExceptionProxy.<init>(StartupExceptionProxy.java:31) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:159) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.execute(CrateDB.java:135) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:85) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.1.4.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.1.4.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:88) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:81) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:268) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:66) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:202) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:202) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:267) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:155) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/data
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:204) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:66) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:202) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:202) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:267) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:155) ~[crate-app-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        ... 6 more
```

I have tried a number of changes however googling the errors brings back, understandably entirely elasticsearch topics, given this is just coming as part of crate a lot of the solutions do not work.

any advice very very gratefully recieved

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: The program just doesn't have access to /home/data: **Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/data**. Grant it read/write access.